# Use an array isse. but its not returning anything to the page

Tags: php, html

I'm having an issue displaying the selected data from the database when using a array. I think the issue I'm having is I do not know how to output the array correctly.

PHP Code

```
$run = array();
$run_query = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM `run_sheet_log`WHERE `user`='$_GET[emp_id]' AND `company_id`='$Company_id' ORDER BY `id` ASC");
while($displayRun = $sql->fetch_array($run_query)){

    $run[] = array('id' => $displayRun['id'],
    'user' => $displayRun['user'],
    'truck' => $displayRun['truck']);
}
```

HTML code

```
<table class="display table shrunk-table" id="run_sheet_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Carrieing</th>
            <th>Pickup</th>
            <th>Dropoff</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><?=$displayRun['id']?></td>
        <td><?=$displayRun['user']?></td>
        <td>France - Calais </td>
        <td>France - Luxemboung </td>
        <td>D <i title="Delivered" class="info c13ADEB glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"</i></td>
        <td><a href="" id="runs_view" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">View</a></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here the view from the browser. http://gyazo.com/b08c7b3f67c06bd87b90f10751a7b17a

Comment: Have you verified that the database is returning the correct data? `var_dump($run_query);` Also, your SQL is vulnerable to SQL injection - you should consider switching to PDO with bound parameters.

Comment: I just added the code var_dump($run_query);. Its displaying this. Is that good?

http://gyazo.com/a6f9620b01cd8de95ca0512e272e91f8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use $run array in this case, the structure of this array:

```
$run = [0] = [ 'id' = <value from DB>,
               'user' = <value from DB>     ]
       [1] = [ 'id' = <value from DB>,
               'user' = <value from DB>     ]
.........
```